# Javascript declare variable in global scope shorthand

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-5

```
var object = {name: "Murad"};
(function(window){
  var a = b = 10;
})(object)
```

Why I can access b variable in global scope?

```
var a = b = 10
```

is not same thing with?

```
window.b = 10;
var a = window.b;
```

Comment: `object` has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Nope has. When U write window.b = 20 inside function b declare inside object

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Since `b` is not in the current scope, it will be put on the outer scope (the global `window` object in the browser)

Comment: try it with `"use strict"`.

Comment: I know when declare variable without var its declare inside global scope but my question is  declare variable without var its convert window.variableName yeah? And i change window object with a. I want do declare variable inside a

Answer (score 2):

You can access variable **b** because you give a variable name - b, but you do not declare it like var let or const. JS will see that a name is allocated for a variable and it will create the variable automatically in the global scope.

Comment: Yeah I know but when u declare variable without var its convert window.variableName yeah? And i change window object with a

Comment: no, it doesn't first convert it to `window.var`, it will actually put it on the global `window` object. It doesn't matter if you have a different `window` in your current scope